# How to solve this connection problem between firebase and flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I added flutter to my android studio. However, while I was trying to connect it to firebase. I can't find the android file in the project section
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have created a Flutter Package and not a Flutter Application.

Consider selecting `Flutter Application` when creating a flutter project.

Then you can see the `android` folder
[image]